# What's the reason for this eslint error and how to fix it?

Tags: typescript, vuex, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am getting the below lint error for the code shown below.
How to fix it?
Unsafe member access .item on an any value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access

[image]

Comment: Searching on the Web for '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access' finds this: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-member-access.md The value `store.state` has type `any`, and this linting rule prevents you from accessing members on `any`. Make sure that `store.state` has a correct type that is not `any`.

Comment: Jesper, please check whether my fix below is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means `store.state` is any. Make sure it has a proper type.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Logan Devine and Jesper for the help.

The type of state was StateInterface.

I fixed the issue by casting the type of state as below. Hope this fix is right.

```
const itemName = computed(() =>  (<StateInterface> store.state).item.itemName)
```

Comment: Looks good, but if this is a React project (or for clarity) use `foo as bar` instead of `<bar>foo` (`(store.state as StateInterface).item.itemName)`)

Comment: Thank you. This is a Vue project. I have changed it to the way suggested by you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
const itemName = computed(() => (store.state as StateInterface).item.itemName)
```